# Scala closures filename

Tags: scala, compiler-construction

I have a problem due to the length of filename that the compilers give to one of my closures inside a Scala class, using Scala 2.9.2

CurrencyInitializer$$anonfun$com$gottex$gottware$server$startup$initializers$impl$currency$CurrencyInitializer$$updateDepositEquivalentBonds$1.class

The problem I have with this filename is that I am uploading a folder contains all my compiled classes through a Linux server through an SSH gui and this fails.

```
private def updateDepositEquivalentBonds(currency: Currency) {

    val depositEquivalentBonds = gottwareDataSource.space.readAllWithCurrency(classOf[DepositEquivalentBondImpl], currency)
    for (depositEquivalentBond <- depositEquivalentBonds) depositEquivalentBond.updateFromDeposit(gottwareDataSource.space)
    if (depositEquivalentBonds.length > 0) {
      gottwareDataSource.space.writeMultiple(depositEquivalentBonds, Lease.FOREVER,
        UpdateModifiers.UPDATE_OR_WRITE | UpdateModifiers.NO_RETURN_VALUE)
      gottwareDataSource.space.writeMultiple(AskBidSpread.newInstances(depositEquivalentBonds.toArray[SecurityImpl]), Lease.FOREVER, UpdateModifiers.UPDATE_OR_WRITE | UpdateModifiers
        .NO_RETURN_VALUE)
}
  }
```

Surprisingly, this is the code that produce the long filename. Is there something I can do on the compiler to prevent this to happen?

Comment: Do you really need to upload a .class file? Wouldn't a .jar file do?

Comment: There is no way to control how the compiler generates internal class names for things like function literals. (And remember, all closures are function literals but not all function literals are closures. Terminology matters. ... Though not for this particular problem...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `max-classfile-name` parameter on the scala compiler invocation to shorten the file names.

In a POM, to get file names no longer than 144 characters (Crypt FS size limit) the configuration looks like

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
         <scalaVersion>2.9.2</scalaVersion>
         <args>
              <arg>-Xmax-classfile-name</arg>
              <arg>144</arg>
         </args>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Compiler source setting reference [link](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/settings/ScalaSettings.scala#L85) (will become obsolete)